# Why eclipse while debugging access areas that has no break points?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

When we debug, breakpoints are set before attaching to the process(even before starting application) and even though there are times that debugger go to places that has not been set to access.

I've checked and not modified the breakpoints list before starting program.

Regards

Comment: in my case that happens  when an exception is thrown by this class.

Comment: Have you set this somewhere in IDE properties or it is done by default ?

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse preferences there is `Java -> Debug`. Check if the option *Suspend execution on uncaught exceptions* is checked. If that option is checked, the debugger will suspend execution when such an exception is thrown.

Comment: Yeap, but even I've unchecked that option it goes there. I do not mean that application

Answer (score 0):

My friend who has no SO has solved that issue. There were break points in library that was imported by debugged project.

Those breakpoints are not visible in main project.